# How to create a local webapp userscript

Tags: unity, 12.10, webapps

I'd like to write my own local webapps userscripts, but I don't want to compile and install the [main webapps source code](https://code.launchpad.net/webapps-applications/) every time.

I would like to keep the original Ubuntu Webapps package installed, but use my local userscripts as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

What you could do is create your userscript and symlink it to `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-$NAME/$NAME.user.js`:

(`$MYSCRIPTPATH` is the full path to your script, probably somewhere in your home directory;`$NAME` is the name of your script)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-$NAME
sudo ln -s $MYSCRIPTPATH /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-$NAME/$NAME.user.js
```

You'll also need to manually create a manifest file on `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-$NAME/manifest.json` - you can just copy one from the other apps in the `userscripts` dir and modify the values according to your webapp.

Comment: You have to add your script in /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/config.xml as well. Just copy and modify another entry.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton, does this still apply? I can't find the `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/config.xml` file anywhere on my system.

Comment: It still applies to 12.04.

Comment: Can you tell me how to compile webapps userscripts?

Comment: config.xml seems to be not needed in 12.10

Comment: @RajatSaxena: no need to compile them... just put in that folder with manifest.json (see other folders)

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy and secure way to create custom web apps: using Firefox and the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) extension. In Greasemonkey, it's enough to create a user script like this (I've created for Asana):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Asana
// @namespace   app.asana.com
// @include     https://app.asana.com/*
// @grant       none
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

window.Unity = external.getUnityObject(1);

Unity.init({ name: 'Asana',
             domain: 'app.asana.com',
             homepage: 'https://app.asana.com/',
             iconUrl: 'http://asana.com/assets/FluidIcon.png' 
});
```

This script simply enable the Unity integration, but you can add other features writing more code.