# Deploy Webapp Locally with Ubuntu SDK

Tags: 14.04, webapps, ubuntu-sdk

I'm not much of a developer, but I was looking to create my own webapps for a couple websites I use. I installed the Ubuntu SDK (14.04) and created a webapp project for the site I want to use. I can run the webapp through the SDK and it comes up and displays properly. But, I am trying to figure out how to have it installed locally. Nothing happens if I click on build. I'm not fully understanding this. I have the default desktop kit setup in the SDK.

What I want to do is take my webapp project and make it so I can simply run it as a program on my Ubuntu desktop (same desktop with the SDK installed). I don't care about publishing it or anything like that.

I've tried searching for good resources and only found the one link on Ubuntu's website on how to create a webapp.

Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried using the click command and read all through the man page for click. I ran click build . and generated the click file for my webapp project. I then tried installing the click package using the pkcon command and received the following: 'Click packages may not be installed directly using dpkg.
Use click install instead.
dpkg: error processing archive /home/username/Documents/Ubuntu SDK Projects/my_webapp/com.ubuntu.developer.username.my_webapp_0.1_all.click (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1'

Comment: I feel I'm definitely going about this wrong. I can also see the webapps I already have on my computer (cnn, facebook, etc) and their manifest files. Is there a way I can just take my manifest.json files from my project and put them on my computer somewhere? I know there is a webapp-container command that I could just place in a script to launch the webapp that I want, but I'd like it integrated better with OS as an application.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problems you did did with pkcon. Thanks for documenting your struggle here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after many searches, I was able to get this working. Here are some links for those having similar issues that helped me:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2167968
[Unity webapp is not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450704/unity-webapp-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)
[How to create a local webapp userscript](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167492/how-to-create-a-local-webapp-userscript)